# I can't connect my Android Devices to my Wifi Hotspot in Linux Mint LMDE 3

Tags: debian, linux-mint, wifi, wifi-hotspot, dhcpcd

I recently installed Linux Mint LMDE 3 on my PC, all normal until today, when I proceed to configure my Wifi Hotspot, I put the SSID of the network, the password, and the surprise? no device has a connection, recognizes the network, but does not assign any IP.

I searched Google for a solution to this problem and it could be that the DHCP service was not installed, I followed [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-isc-dhcp-server-in-debian-9/) tutorial to try to solve it and nothing.

I leave here below, the content of the configuration files of the programs involved.

the /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf file

```
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;

    max-lease-time 7200;
    #ping true;
    option domain-name-servers 172.27.15.2, 10.72.81.2;
    option domain-name "example.com";
    authorative;
    log-facility local7;

    subnet 10.42.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 10.42.0.1 10.42.0.99;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.254, 10.128.254.254;
    option domain-name "example.com";
    option routers 192.168.1.1;
    option netbios-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
    option netbios-node-type 8;
    get-lease-hostnames true;
    use-host-decl-names true;
    default-lease-time 600;
    max-lease-time 7200;
    }
```

And here is the /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server file

```
# Defaults for isc-dhcp-server (sourced by /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server)

# Path to dhcpd's config file (default: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf).
DHCPDv4_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
#DHCPDv6_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf

# Path to dhcpd's PID file (default: /var/run/dhcpd.pid).
DHCPDv4_PID=/var/run/dhcpd.pid
#DHCPDv6_PID=/var/run/dhcpd6.pid

# Additional options to start dhcpd with.
#   Don't use options -cf or -pf here; use DHCPD_CONF/ DHCPD_PID instead
#OPTIONS=""

# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#   Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACESv4="enp1s5 wlxf8d111b4f797"
INTERFACESv6=""
```

And this is the exit of the command `systemctl status isc-dhcp-server`

```
● isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-12-02 15:33:32 -04; 1h 7min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

dic 02 15:33:32 bryan-useche isc-dhcp-server[803]: Configuration file errors encountered -- exiting
dic 02 15:33:32 bryan-useche isc-dhcp-server[803]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
dic 02 15:33:32 bryan-useche isc-dhcp-server[803]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
dic 02 15:33:32 bryan-useche isc-dhcp-server[803]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
dic 02 15:33:32 bryan-useche isc-dhcp-server[803]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
dic 02 15:33:32 bryan-useche isc-dhcp-server[803]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
dic 02 15:33:32 bryan-useche isc-dhcp-server[803]: exiting.
dic 02 15:33:32 bryan-useche systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: DHCP server.
dic 02 15:33:32 bryan-useche systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
dic 02 15:33:32 bryan-useche systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run `dhcpd -t` then it will test the file and report on possible errors.

In this case it responds...

```
subnet 10.42.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0: bad subnet number/mask combination.
    subnet 10.42.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 
                                         ^
```

Your network should be `10.42.0.0`

Unrelated, but maybe a potential issue in the next step, your router definition (`192.168.1.1`) isn't reachable from the `10.42.0.0/255.255.255.0` network, so the devices may get an IP address but they won't be able to route anywhere.

Comment: I made the modification, but the exit by systemd is the same, exit with status 1.

Comment: Make sure `dhcpd -t` reports clean.

Comment: `dhcpd -t` reports the three files and nothing more

Comment: this is the exit when i execute `journalctl -xe` `No subnet declaration for wlxf8d111b4f797 (no IPv4 addresses).Ignoring requests on wlxf8d111b4f797.  If this is not what you want, please write a subnet declaration in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
to which interface wlxf8d111b4f797 is attached.  
No subnet declaration for enp1s5 (192.168.0.235).
Ignoring requests on enp1s5.If this is not what
you want, please write a subnet declaration
in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
to which interface enp1s5 is attached.
Not configured to listen on any interfaces!`

Comment: The last line `Not configured to listen on any interfaces!` is the important one; that's saying that `10.42.0.0` isn't associated with any network interface on your server.  Your DHCP server can only serve addresses related to IP addresses on interfaces it knows about.  This is related to the 192.168 comment I originally made

Comment: I'm surrender, i'm going back to Linux Mint Tara again, i will put the topic as NOT Solved and Finished. thanks a lot for your help.